# Call code method on application start (without having to call @onclick)

Tags: blazor

How can I fire the StartClock() function when the component loads, without having to call @onclick event ?

```
@page "/clock"
@using System.Threading;

<p @onclick=@StartClock>@currenttime</p>

@code
 {
    string currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    void StartClock()
    {
        var timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(_ =>
        {
            InvokeAsync(() => {
                currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }), null, 1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Call it in OnAfterRender

Comment: Thanks, I feel foolish now. +1 sir

Answer (score 0):

Here´s the update code after @Rich Bryant answer

```
@page "/clock"
@using System.Threading;

<p>@currenttime</p>

@code
 {
    private string currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    private void StartClock()
    {
        var timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(_ =>
        {
            InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }), null, 1000, 1000);
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        StartClock();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should test `firstRender == true`, the component can be rendered multiple times. More, you should implement IDisposable to dispose the timer.